# Azure Service bus data Restricting

Tags: azureservicebus

Is it possible to restrict the Azure Service bus queue to accept only one type of data(eg. JSON) and avoid other type of data (like javascript)

By this way I need to provide more security to the system.

I am using C# MVC 5 for development

Answer (score 0):

You cannot restrict the message sent to the Queue based on it's type. As there is no option provided for Service Bus Queues, you can have the restriction in the Server where the messages are sent to the Queue.

Another option should be using Topic Subscriptions, which allows rules to be configured for the Subscriptions and based on the evaluation of the rules, the messages will get in to the Subscriptions. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/topic-filters) for more details about configuring rules.

Answer (score 0):

Queues are generally **not a good fit for querying and advanced filtering scenarios**. Peeking through a large queue when a customer checks for status would defeat the whole purpose of using a service bus.

> Messages are sent to a topic and delivered to one or more associated subscriptions, depending on filter rules that can be set on a per-subscription basis. The subscriptions can use additional filters to restrict the messages that they want to receive.

As Arunprabhu said, you could try to use rules in topic filter to restrict message type.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-queues-topics-subscriptions).